# How to show the description of event with Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I try to use Google Calendar API for an RSS events but there I can't find any parameter to show me the description of my event. All I can see is the name of event and the date.

This are my request parameters

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": etag,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "items": [
    events Resource
  ]
}
```

you will find each item is an [events resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)  there is more then just name and date returned

Comment: appendPre(event.summary + event.description + ' (' + when + ')'); but the result is -- my event -- undefined -- time -- so how to show the description then?